# Focus on GtkGlArea not getting captured

Tags: c++, gtk3

My application consists of a tree view with files that the user can click on. Based on the file the preview area will show the appropriate control to display that file. For some files that is a `GtkGlArea` that is rendering the content. It includes a camera that should be movable using the keyboard and mouse.

When a file is clicked the following happens (inside the event handler of the `changed` event of the `GtkTreeView`)

```
if (mActiveView->needsOpenGL()) {
    gtk_widget_show(mGlControl);
    gtk_widget_grab_focus(mGlControl);
} else {
    gtk_widget_hide(mGlControl);
}
```

The `mGlControl` is created using a `GtkBuilder` that reads my Glade UI template. The control has the flags `Visible`, `Can focus`, `Application paintable`, `Double Buffered`, `Sensitive` and the events `Pointer Motion`, `Button Press`, `Button Release`, `Key Press`, `Key Release`, `Focus Change`, `Structure`

However when an element is clicked in the tree view the focus stays on that item and when I use my keyboard it is reflected in the tree view (using arrow up selects the next item for example).

Is it possible to put the focus on a GtkGlArea?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the intuition I had after re-reading my posted question was correct. It seems switching focus inside the event handler of the tree view change event was not working. I *think* the chain of events is probably like this:

- Item is clicked
- Changed event is handled and delegated -> focus set on the gl control
- "Click" event on the item is handled -> focus set on the tree view item

It seems the focus logic for clicking an item is done after the change event is issued.

I adapted my code to look like this:

```
if (mActiveView->needsOpenGL()) {
    gtk_widget_show(mGlControl);
    runInMainThread([this]() { gtk_widget_grab_focus(mGlControl); });
} else {
    gtk_widget_hide(mGlControl);
}
```

This is a convenience method:

```
void MainWindow::runInMainThread(const std::function<void()> &callback) {
    g_idle_add(callbacks::mainThreadCallback, new callbacks::FunctionHolder{callback});
}
```

And should delay it for after the processing of the click event and now the tree view item gets properly defocused.